# ¿Cómo identifico un numero capicúa negativo?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

La función recibirá un numero x y deberá determinar si es capicúa o no.

Este deberá devolver verdadero(true) si es capicúa y falso(false) si no lo es.

Además deberemos contemplar los siguientes escenarios:

- Contemplar que el numero que llega puede ser negativo.
- Contemplar que el numero que llega puede ser de un digito, si es así debe devolver true.
- Contemplar que el numero que llega puede ser null, si es así debe devolver false.

@param num
@return esPalindromo

```
public Boolean numeroCapicua(Integer num) {
    int x = 0;
    
    String palabra = String.valueOf(num);

    for (int i = 0, j = palabra.length() - 1; i <= j; i++, --j) {
        if (palabra.charAt(i) != palabra.charAt(j)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

cuando lo valido en el main, el negativo es el unico que me da mal

```
assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(123454321));
assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(-123454321)); 
assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(2)); 
assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(0)); 
assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(null)); 
assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(231)); 
assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(123)); 
assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y el problema es??????????

Comment: hola! cuando lo valido en el main, el negativo es el unico que me da mal                                   
        assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(123454321));
        assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(-123454321));
        assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(2));
        assertEquals(true, pr.numeroCapicua(0));
        assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(null));
        assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(231));
        assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(123));
        assertEquals(false, pr.numeroCapicua(Integer.MAX_VALUE));

Comment: Porque estas comparando el signo - con el ultimo caracter.. negativo o positivo no tiene nada que ver con capicua... sacale el signo y listo... Y ese error, en tu comentario, tiene que ir en la pregunta.. en tu pregunta nunca pusiste cual es tu problema....

Comment: Igual puedes comparar los valores absolutos

Answer (score 2):

A ver si te sirve

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //instanciamos la clase escaner
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    //declaramos tres variables booleanas a false
    boolean esNumero = false, entrada = false, valor = false;
    //vairable string vacía
    String n = "";
    //variable de número largo a cero
    long numero = 0;
    
    //bucle do while
    do{      
        //si la variable booleana esNumero es igual a true
        if (esNumero){
            //llamamos al método obtener inverso y recibimos el resultado en numero enviando el número por parámetro como string
            numero = metodoObtenerInverso(n);
            //pasamos el string del número a número largo
            long nN = Integer.parseInt(n);
            //llamamos al método comprobar capicua, enviamos por parámetro el número recibido por teclado y su inverso y obtenemos un booleano si es o no capicua
            boolean capicua = metodoComprobarCapicua(nN, numero);
            //si es capicua
            if (capicua){
                //si es positivo
                if (valor){
                    //imprime la leyenda
                    System.out.println("El número introducido es positivo y capicua");
                    //pone la variable a false si se quiere reiniciar el programa
                    esNumero = false;
                    //si queremos cerrar el programa ponemos descomentamos la siguiente línea que pone en false la variable del bucle do while
                    //entrada = false;
                }
                //si es negativo
                else{
                    //imprimimos la leyenda
                    System.out.println("El número introducido es negativo y capicua");
                    //pone la variable a false si se quiere reiniciar el programa
                    esNumero = false;
                    //si queremos cerrar el programa ponemos descomentamos la siguiente línea que pone en false la variable del bucle do while
                    //entrada = false;
                }
            }
            //si no es capicua
            else{
                //si es positivo
                if (valor){
                    System.out.println("El número introducido es positivo, pero NO es capicua");
                    //entrada = false;
                    esNumero = false;
                }
                //si no es positivo
                else {
                    System.out.println("El número introducido es negativo y NO es capicua");
                    //entrada = false;
                    esNumero = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //si la variable es igual a false por no haber sido evaluada o no ser un número lo introducido por teclado
        else {          
            //pedimos un número         
            System.out.println("Ponga un número: ");
            //recogemos el número en la variable string n
            n = teclado.nextLine();
            //llamamos al método comprobar si es número enviando el número por parámetro como string y recibiendo un booleano con el resultado
            esNumero = metodoComprobarNumero(n);
            //si es un número
            if (esNumero){
                //pasamos el string a número largo
                long NN = Integer.parseInt(n);
                //llamamos al método para comprobar si es positivo o negativo y recibimos el rsultado en la variable booleana
                valor = metodoComprobarPositivo(NN);
                //si es negativo
                if (valor == false){
                    //llamamos al método enviando el número negativo por parámatro para cambiar su signo y recibimos el resultado
                    long lNN = metodoCambiarNegativo(NN);
                    //sustituimos el número negativo por el positivo en la variable que será utilizada
                    n = String.valueOf(lNN);
                }
            }
            //ponemos la variable a true
            entrada = true;
        }
    //repetiremos el bucle mientras entrada tenga el valor true
    } while(entrada == true);
}
//método que comprueba si lo introducido por teclado es o no es número
private static boolean metodoComprobarNumero(String n) { 
    //variable booleana a false   
    boolean numero = false;
    //método try catch
    try {
        //si es posible convertir el string en número
        Integer.parseInt(n);
        //ponemos la variable a true, pues es un número
        numero = true;
    } 
    //si se produce una excepción por no ser un número
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
       //ponemos la variable a false
       numero = false;
    }
    //si no es un número
    if (numero == false){
        //lo decimos por consola imprimiendo el texto
        System.out.println("El número introducido no es correcto");
    }
//retornamos el valor de la variable
return numero;
}

//metodo que crea el inverso del número 
private static int metodoObtenerInverso(String n) {
    //variable string vacía
    String proNumero = "";
    //creamos un array char con la longitud de los dígitos del número
    char[] arrayNumero = new char[n.length()];
    //creamos otro char array con los dígitos del números
    char[] arrayN = n.toCharArray();
    //creamos un contador con el valor de la cantidad de dígitos del número
    int contador = n.length();
    
    //creamos un bucle que haga tantas iteraciones como dígitos tenga el número
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++){
        //almacenamos en el array, su contrario en el otro array
        arrayNumero[i] = arrayN[contador - 1];
        //vamos agregando los valores del array creado al string
        proNumero = proNumero + arrayNumero[i];
        //descontamos uno al contador
        contador--;
    }
    //convertimos el string en número
    int numero = Integer.parseInt(proNumero);
    //lo retornamos a la llamada
    return numero;
}

//método que comprueba si es o no es positivo que recibe el número por parámetro
private static boolean metodoComprobarPositivo(long numero) {
    //declaramos la variable a falso
    boolean valor = false;
    //si el número es mayor o igual a cero lo consideramos positivo
    if (numero >= 0){
        //ponemos la variable a true
        valor = true;
    }
    //retornamos la variable
    return valor;
}

//método que pasa el número negativo recibido por parámetro a positivo 
private static long metodoCambiarNegativo(long numero) {
    //multiplica el número por - 1 para cambiarle el signo
    numero = numero * (-1);
    //retorna el número positivo
    return numero;
}

//método que compueba si es capicua, que recibe el número y su inverso por parámetro
private static boolean metodoComprobarCapicua(long nN, long numero) {
    //convierte en string los números recibidos por parámtro
    String sN = String.valueOf(nN);
    String sNumero = String.valueOf(numero);
    //crea a true la variable booleana capicua
    boolean capicua = true;
    //creamos dos arrays char con ambos string de los números
    char[] arrayN = sN.toCharArray();
    char[] arrayNumero = sNumero.toCharArray();
    
    //bucle para recorrer los array
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayN.length; i++){
        //si el valor de los dos arrays en la posición de iteración no es igual
        if (arrayN[i] != arrayNumero[i]){
            //ponemos la variable a falso
            capicua = false;
        }           
    }
    //retornamos el valor de la variable
    return capicua;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haz una función donde ese número lo transforme en string, divida por la mitad el número y de la segunda mitad, te lo muestre a la inversa para ver si son iguales. Luego solo comprueba que el número contenta el símbolo menos. Si cumple todo eso, es capicúa negativo.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.